# pros and cons of unix socket, message queue

Tags: ipc, message-queue, unix-socket

I'm just learning the concept of IPC. FIFO, Unix socket, Message Queue, Share memory etc...

I also want to learn the pros and cons about these methods.
But I can't find the information about Unix socket & Message Queue.

Can someone give me some briefly pros and cons about these two methods ?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The question is too broad for SO